# Swift - SpriteKit CGPoint Alignment

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on a project in swift and I am able to make a sprite. I am trying to make a sprite at a number of different locations. As a test I replaced the code in the game scene to be:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView){
        let wall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Wall")
        wall.position = CGPoint(x: 289, y: 0)
    }    
}
```

What I do not understand is this code makes a sprite in the lower left corner. As expected in the y direction only half of the sprite shows, but the x direction seems completely off. If I try to set the x value to any number below 289 it will not appear.  Is the 0,0 point really 289,0 or am I missing something? I am programming for iphone 6 if that makes a difference.

Thank you!

Comment: Your scene it is not necessarily the same size of your view

Comment: Ah I see. Is there any way to check what the size of the scene is? I used UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.size to get the bounds. Would that be the resolution the game will show up in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scene it is not necessarily the same size of your view. You can check the size of your scene as follow:

```
view.scene!.frame.size
view.scene!.frame.width
view.scene!.frame.height
view.scene!.frame.midX
view.scene!.frame.midY
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still really new to this!