# Cannot place a label in the center of a scene in Swift

Tags: swift

I am attempting to place a UILabel in the very center of my scene. I do this by getting the center value and then using to convertPointToView function, then subtracting the width and the result is not in the center. If anyone could show me why what I am doing is wrong or perhaps even fix it for me I, would very much appreciate it. Here's the result: (http://i1087.photobucket.com/albums/j461/niiooo/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-10%20at%205.26.37%20PM.png)

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var testSprite: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
var testLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

func defineTestLabel(var #label: UILabel) -> UILabel {
    var labelXPos: Int = Int()

    labelXPos = Int(convertPointToView(CGPoint(x: (self.size.width / 2)  - 50, y: 0)).x)
    label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: labelXPos, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    label.text = "Test"
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    label.layer.borderWidth = 5
    return label
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.view?.addSubview(defineTestLabel(label:self.testLabel))
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}
```

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/30120008/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus well if it is, (view.scene!.frame.size / 2) - 75 isn't the center either so how do I put a UILabel in the center of the screen?

Comment: @LeoDabus sorry but I don't understand, can you elaborate in your answer?

Comment: view.scene!.frame.midX

Comment: You probably need to subtract half of the label width

Comment: Yay! thanks, if you submit that as an answer, I'll check mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the scene midX minus half of your label width.