# Swift - set position

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

How I can set the position of the colored bar to the bottom of the screen?

I have these lines:

```
let ground = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor(red: 144/255, green: 100/255,
blue: 144/255, alpha: 1.0) , size: CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 20))
ground.position = ???
addChild(ground)
```

Comment: This depends on your device orientation and if you have made any modifications to your view controller

Comment: You have to use the scene maxY or minY. Your scene it is not the same size of your view

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/30120008/2303865

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
let ground = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor(red: 144/255, green: 100/255,
        blue: 144/255, alpha: 1.0) , size: CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: 20))
ground.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
ground.position =  CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
addChild(ground)
```

Possible pitfalls:
You must reposition if an orientation change happens. Also make sure that the scene is not bigger as the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try with these lines of code:

```
let ground = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor(red: 144/255, green: 100/255,
blue: 144/255, alpha: 1.0) , size: CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 20))

view.addSubview(ground)

ground.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor).active = true
ground.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor).active = true
ground.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.widthAnchor).active = true
ground.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(40).active = true
```