# why is self.frame.maxY not showing on the screen for iPad

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, cgpoint

I am building a game with swift and sprite kit and I want to place a sprite on the very top of the screen.

when I do `sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: self.frame.maxY)` on an iPhone it places the sprite on the top, however on an iPad it does not  show anywhere (I'm guessing the sprite is above the max Y value of the iPad)

how can I make it so the sprite is on top of the screen for both the iPad, and iPhone. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/30120008/2303865

Comment: Learn about aspect ratio and anchor points

Comment: I could not find any tutorials for aspect ratio and anchor points while using `SKScene`.

Comment: Learn about aspect ratio in general.  Also to say you can’t find any means you aren’t looking because I have covered both topics extensively.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try increasing the x:0 value
If increasing this value shows the Sprite.
The problem is most likely your project using GameScene.sks

Comment: This won't do anything.  His problem is his scene is 9:16, but an ipad is 3:4. so maxY is being cropped off due to the different aspect ratio.