# How to randomly spawn enemies on my screen

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Here is my code for enemy spawn:

```
let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(2)
let x: CGFloat = randomNumber == 0 ? 1 : -1
enemy.position = CGPoint(x: (CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UIScreen.main.bounds.width))) * x), y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
```

It works but some of my enemies are spawning outside of my screen. What can I change to make them all spawn inside the border?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/30120008/2303865

Comment: Why arc4random? Just use `CGFloat.random(in: 1...100)`

Comment: @aheze the main issue is that OP is using the screen bounds which is not necessarily the same size as the scene. Check the link above

Comment: @LeoDabus i changed it to self and it still doesnt work

Comment: @nathandr not sure what you mean. You need to generate a point using the scene size not the screen bounds

Comment: You cannot used the screen size because the scene size depends on your game scene (`SKScene`).

Comment: @nathandr something like `let x = CGFloat.random(in: .zero ..< view.scene!.frame.width)` and  `let y = CGFloat.random(in: .zero ..< view.scene!.frame.height)`

Comment: If you want to use a fixed y position `view.scene!.frame.maxY`

Comment: ok would this also spawn in all device screen sizes, like iphone vs ipad

Comment: also couldnt i just replace UIscreen with self.frame.width?

Comment: @nathandr as I said you need the scene size. Whatever you are trying to do just make sure to use the `view.scene`

Answer (score 0):

honestly haven't the foggiest clue what this is, but it seems like something is being multiplied by x, which would put it outside of its bounds, maybe not all, but if they happen to spawn at a particularly large (or negative) number.

Comment: I'm not sure why you've got the downvote here because I think you're spot on. They are generating a random number from 0 - the screen width. And then multiplying that by -1 and so will end up spawning the thing off the left hand edge of the screen.

Comment: x is a random number with a value of 1 or -1. The code to create it was in the question but not formatted as code, so easy to miss.

Comment: @SteveIves yes, that's correct. So... when it is -1 the CGPoint will have some negative x value. And so be off the left edge of the screen/view/scene.

Comment: thanks that actually solved the problem without trying to replace the code. It now sometimes spawns right on the edge of the screen. So if i did want to change it so its not right on the edge of the screen,  do i just put a specific value range. Like 500 - 300 so it doesnt spawn right on the edge