# Find screen resolution in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, screen, resolution

I am writing an iOS game in Swift using Spritekit and want to find the screen resolution to properly place my sprites. I found multiple ways on internet, but none of them is giving me a correct resolution that help me to place my sprites.
The one that works fine for an iPhone 13 Pro is the following

```
screenSize=self.size
screenSize.width /= (UIScreen.main.bounds.height/screenSize.height) / (UIScreen.main.bounds.width/screenSize.width)

let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Landscape.jpg")
background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
background.size = screenSize
```

If I use the recommended `UIScreen.main.bounds`, this is the outcome on an iPhone:
[image]
But on an iPad for example, the dimensions are too big.
Is there a unique way of finding screen resolution on all devices ? Or is there a scene scaling that enters in the equation ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// Get main screen bounds
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height

print("Screen width = \(screenWidth), screen height = \(screenHeight)")
```

this is output of iPone 13 pro simulator:

```
Screen width = 390.0, screen height = 844.0
```

Comment: It indeed gives me the same values than yours', but this is too small. Dimensions that work to expand or place my sprite are w=616, h=1334 (1.57x bigger). Where can I find that 1.57 ?

Comment: I have added a screenshot to show the UIScreen outcome

Comment: @LaurentCrivello your scene is not necessarily the same size of the device's screen. Check the duplicated post https://stackoverflow.com/a/30120008/2303865

Comment: OK, thanks. Hence what would be the best way to find the visible part of the screen for me to place the sprites ?